# Extracting MS Word Table Cell as image?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to extract table cells as images. The cells may contain mixed content (Text + Image), which I need to merge into a single image. I am able to get the core text but I have no idea to get an image+text.
 Not sure if Apace POI would help.

Has anyone done something like this earlier?

```
  public static void readTablesDataInDocx(XWPFDocument doc) {
    int tableIdx = 1;
    int rowIdx = 1;
    int colIdx = 1;
    List table = doc.getTables();
    System.out.println("==========No Of Tables in Document=============================================" + table.size());
    for (int k = 0; k < table.size(); k++) {
        XWPFTable xwpfTable = (XWPFTable) table.get(k);
        System.out.println("================table -" + tableIdx + "===Data==");
        rowIdx = 1;
        List row = xwpfTable.getRows();
        for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
            XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow = (XWPFTableRow) row.get(j);
            System.out.println("Row -" + rowIdx);
            colIdx = 1;
            List cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells();
            for (int i = 0; i < cell.size(); i++) {
                XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell = (XWPFTableCell) cell.get(i);
                if (xwpfTableCell != null) {
                    System.out.print("\t" + colIdx + "- column value: " + xwpfTableCell.getText());
                }
                colIdx++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
            rowIdx++;
        }
        tableIdx++;
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Now I am able to get Text with the help of this method

```
System.out.print("\t" + colIdx + "- column value: " + xwpfTableCell.getText());
```

How do I get the Image if a cell also contains one?

Comment: Try getting the paragraphs in the cell `getParagraphs()`, then for each paragraph, get the runs `getRuns()`. This returns a [XWPFRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html). This has a method that allows you to get pictures: `getEmbeddedPictures()`

Comment: @iggymoran
List para = xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs();
if (para != null) {
XWPFRun xWPFRun = (XWPFRun) para.get(i);
for (int l = 0; l < para.size(); l++) {
System.out.print("\t" + colIdx + "- column Image: " + xWPFRun.getEmbeddedPictures());
                            }
                        }
getting class cast exception..

Comment: You want to try something like: `para.getRuns()`, verify that they're not null, and then call `run.getEmbeddedPictures()`.

Comment: para is having List type so how do i call getRuns() using para ?

Comment: I've posted an answer as it can be more descriptive than comments, but you can call the method once you've verified that your cell is not null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code, it's working for me

```
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            List<XWPFTable> table = doc.getTables();
            for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table) {
                List<XWPFTableRow> row = xwpfTable.getRows();
                for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : row) {
                    List<XWPFTableCell> cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells();
                    for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : cell) {
                        if (xwpfTableCell != null) {
                            System.out.println(xwpfTableCell.getText());
                            String s = xwpfTableCell.getText();
                            for (XWPFParagraph p : xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs()) {
                                for (XWPFRun run : p.getRuns()) {
                                    for (XWPFPicture pic : run.getEmbeddedPictures()) {
                                        byte[] pictureData = pic.getPictureData().getData();
                                        System.out.println("picture : " + pictureData);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have a [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html), you can get hold of the [paragraphs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#getParagraphs()) that form that Cell. These paragraphs are in turn formed by [Run](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html)s, which you can  obtain by calling the [`getRuns`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#getRuns()) method. Runs themselves can contain embedded images, which you can obtain by calling the [`getEmbeddedPictures`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#getEmbeddedPictures()) method.

You can therefore have a method that gets the embedded pictures of a cell:

```
public static void printDescriptionOfImagesInCell(XWPFTableCell cell) {
    List<XWPFParagraph> paragrahs = cell.getParagraphs();
    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
        for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
            List<XWPFPicture> pictures = run.getEmbeddedPictures();
            for (XWPFPicture picture : pictures) {
                //Do anything you want with the picture:
                System.out.println("Picture: " + picture.getDescription());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to discover more things about the actual pictures with the [Picture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFPicture.html) documentation, and change the method to actually get the image data, name, etc.